# Phaser3, Creating Rounded Rectangle, Not Staying Put Relative To Window

Tags: javascript, camera, game-engine, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a scoreboard using phaser3. It creates the board when I do the following in create function:

```
    this.gr = this.add.graphics();

    this.gr.fillStyle(0xffffff, 0.3);

    this.gr.fillRoundedRect(32, 32, 100, 300, 32);

    this.gr.fillStyle(0xff00ff, 1);
```

But it creates it in the top left of the game world and not the screen itself (I'm having to travel to top left of the map to see it rather it being top left relative to window). For context, this is alike agar.io where the player moves around the map with the camera clipped to them.

I tried updating the position using the character sprite's position, but it doesn't flex like it should, and there's probably a more proper way of doing it.

Question: how can I have it be visible relative to the window and not game world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YourGraphic.setScrollFactor(0,0);